R8 Minification Fails After Upgrading to Jetpack Compose BOM 2024.06.00 with SDK 34 Migration
I recently upgraded my project from Compose BOM 2023.06.01 to 2024.06.00 after migrating to SDK 34. While the debug build works fine, the release build fails during the R8 minification step with multiple META-INF errors from Compose, followed by a "class defined multiple times" error in a dynamic feature module.
To address the META-INF errors, I excluded the problematic files from my dynamic feature module, which required individually adding all the excludes:
Dynamic Feature build.gradle:
implementation(project(path: ':mobile')) {
    exclude group: "com.russhwolf"
    exclude group: "androidx.compose.*"
    exclude group: "androidx.compose.material3"
    exclude group: "androidx.compose.material"
    exclude group: "androidx.compose.animation"
    exclude group: "androidx.compose.foundation"
    exclude group: "androidx.compose.ui"
    exclude group: "androidx.compose.runtime"
    exclude group: "androidx.collection.ArrayMap"
}

After adding these excludes, I encountered a new error:
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type androidx.collection.ArrayMap$EntrySet is defined multiple times: /APP-android/mobile/build/intermediates/module_and_runtime_deps_classes/standard_charlesRelease/mergeStandard_charlesReleaseClasses/base.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMap$EntrySet.class, /APP-android/dynamicFeature/build/intermediates/module_and_runtime_deps_classes/standard_charlesRelease/mergeStandard_charlesReleaseClasses/feature-alt_acco.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMap$EntrySet.class","sources":[{"file":"/APP-android/mobile/build/intermediates/module_and_runtime_deps_classes/standard_charlesRelease/mergeStandard_charlesReleaseClasses/base.jar"}],"tool":"R8"}

Environment:

Gradle version: 8.3.0
AGP: 8.4
Kotlin: 1.9.22
Target SDK: 34

This error appeared only after the Compose upgrade, even though ArrayMap isn't part of Compose. The app was working fine after the SDK 34 migration and before the Compose upgrade.
Questions:

Why is this error appearing after upgrading to Compose BOM 2024.06.00?
How can I resolve the "Type defined multiple times" issue in the release build?
If it's a library version conflict, how do I determine which version is causing the issue?

Any help would be appreciated!
